# RegEx - Second Capture Group

Tags: regex

https://regex101.com/r/cI9hI6/1

I have two capturing groups. Could anyone explain me why the second capturing group, which has the order to not match digits: [^\d] is still matching the address which has digits?
I'm slightly confused...

Thanks in advance

EDIT: [^0-9] was still selecting the lines with numbers because it was inside a capture group, my bad, my question didn't even make sense in the first place.

Comment: Excuse me, could you clarify? `.+` will match anything other than a newline, and `[^0-9]` in your pattern just matches a newline with non-digits after it. What do you need to match? What is the issue?

Comment: You got the `[^0-9]*.+` part wrong. It's matching 0 or more non-digits characters then, it's matching everything that is not a new line.

Comment: Oh, I see. That explains it all! So I just realized I could have matched the two different lines with just (?.+)(?\n.+)... It was that simple..

Comment: @R.Durão What about the "order to not match digits" thing?

Comment: By `(?.+)(?\n.+)`, you meant `(?.+)\n(?.+)`, right? I'm pretty sure you don't want the new line in your addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the `[^0-9]*.+` part wrong. It's matching 0 or more non-digits characters then, it's matching everything that is not a new line.

If your file is **correctly formatted** exactly as it is in the Regex101 link you provided, try this Regex instead:

```regex
(?'Company'.+)\n(?'Address'.+)
```

That said, I think your question deserve a little bit of editing for clarification...

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified things better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Basicly I was just confused because I was trying to not match the lines which had numbers in it by using the [^\d], although, i was putting that inside a capture group, which is obviously not going to work. Although, if I had done it like this: (?'Company'.+)[^\d]*.+ it would have worked just fine. Sorry for the confusion, I'm still new to RegEx!

Comment: @R.Durão Cool, glad you finally got it. Regex is fun, you'll see. You just need to learn about it but once you get it, it's a little logical puzzle everytime you want to achieve something.